# I have installed ubuntu 20.04, but I am having issues with booting after I boot in windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows

After I boot once into Windows, to boot into Linux I have to keep pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to pause start up. Then I press <kbd>F9</kbd> key to go to the boot menu and choose “Boot from EFI File”. Then I have to choose a file system followed by selecting  file, followed by choosing  and then by `shimx64.efi` to finally boot into Ubuntu.

I do not want to do this everytime I boot.

How can I resolve this issue?

PS: I can attach images of the options and menus if needed.

PS: I also tried to change the priority of boot order (or something similar by choosing BIOS setup), but in UEFI boot order, it shows:

```
USB Flash Drive/USB Hard Disk
USB CD/DVD ROM Drive
OS Boot Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your bios settings under boot settings  alter the priority of your Linux boot entry once you make this the first source to boot from you will be greeted with friendly GRUB interface which will give you an interface from which you will be able to select which operating system you would like to boot from.

Try Boot Repair if you don't see your Linux entry:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I just added a PS in the question. There seems to be no linux entry in the boot order.

Comment: @AJ there must be options under OS Boot Manager can you provide more info about your machine also try boot options menu from F12 / F10 and see if Ubuntu is listed there during startup. If  not we can setup a new entry for Ubuntu manually

Comment: [Machine Information](https://support.hp.com/ph-en/document/c07550047)

Comment: @AJ I have a similar machine and in F9 Boot Menu I can see both Linux and Windows options listed and in BIOS settings under system configuration under UEFI Boot Order I can see OS Boot Manager and if you select that with return key I can see both options listed .. https://imgur.com/a/DZKBsJq   ,  https://imgur.com/a/TULAdb3 if you dont see this we will have to setup an entry for ubunut .. do you see windows listed there ?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/HntxCcH) is what I see! Let me know if you need more images of all the options as per the question!

Comment: @AJ I can see that system failed to log Ubuntu boot entry for some reason please try boot repair if that does not work we can try something else!

Comment: Where to see boot repair option? What does it do? I can log into ubuntu 20.04 after choosing boot from efi file!

Comment: @AJ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair its safe your grub is probably broken and therefore there is no entry in the bios it will help you configure your ubtunu boot properly  I know you can boot from efi file but this will help you regenerate broken grub / entries and solve your issue

Comment: Okay possible to do boot repair if worse comes to worst. I am now trying to reinstall ubuntu 20.04. I have an option of device for boot loader installation. Which one do I choose here?

Comment: Choose Grub(2). After booting into Ubuntu you should be ok. A grub that works and from which you can choose between Ubuntu and Windows. Reinstalling was really not necessary, just a ```sudo apt remove grub```and a ```sudo apt install grub``` would do the trick.